# is it must to have svn in jenkins slave machine?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-build

I have followed SO forum and created 2 slave nodes.

slave_1 : has svn installed : works fine

slave_2 : has NO svn installed : it unable to checkout the files during build.

Do I reach the conclusion that

> I must have SVN installed in jenkins slave machine also?

Answer (score 0):

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Checkout-Failure-in-Master-Slave-Configuration-td4544736.html
Says I have to install SVN in slave machine too.